# twitter-bootstrap closing alert does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get it to work. When I click the close button, nothing happens.

here's the code:

```
 <div class=" alert alert-error alert-block" style="width:200px" >
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <span>errors</span>            
    </div>
```

I've reproduced the issue on jsfiddler:  http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/7L7Nd/

EDIT

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "quoteWizard" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="ModelType" value="CarQuoteRequestViewModel" />


    ViewBag.ValidationSummaryClass = ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? "validation-summary-valid" : "validation-summary-errors";

    <div class="@ViewBag.ValidationSummaryClass alert alert-error in fade" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <span>Before you can continue, please make sure you have completed the mandatory fields
            highlighted below.</span>
        <ul style="display: none" />
    </div>



    @RenderSection("QuoteSection")

    <div class="ui-formwizard-nav">
        <input id="back" value="@Resource.Global.Previous" type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input id="next" value="@Resource.Global.Next" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Please mention in your question that you have this issue on your website , The jsfiddle you have provided didnt included the jquery , so we are not suppose to know miraculously that you have jquery placed on your site and the issue is something else , isnt it ?

Comment: I was having a similar problem and needed a newer version of jQuery than 1.5, drupal was loading an old version, so I used the Drupal jQuery Update module. Thought this might help someone having this problem.

Comment: you placed the span outside of the button. It should be inside according to the getbootstrap.com docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've sorted it out.

Instead of using a button, I'm now using a span, so the form doesn't get submitted:

```
        <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: The original bootstrap uses an <a> tag. Changing it to <span> worked like you said. Nice workaround.

Answer (score 22):

It appears that the order in which you include the Javascript sources is important. First load jQuery, *then* the Bootstrap Javascript.

E.g. This *fails*:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and this *works*:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You'll also see this in the example templates. From the [Hero template](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html):

```
[...]
<script src="/../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="/../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
[...]
```

Comment: Wonder why order matters..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edited from Shail that just changing from alert-error to alert-danger

```
<div class=" alert alert-danger alert-block" style="width:200px">
     <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <span>
             Before you can continuelds
             highlighted below.
     </span>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/7L7Nd/36/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ok @cpburnz, i'm sorry, i was newbie, i didn't know yet about that rules before, and i just want to help and i'm not a spammer, swear. I was try shail's code in my real programme and it didn't work if i putted **alert-error**, so i changed the allert become **alert-danger**, and it worked well smoothly, that's all. I just wanna help that's all, and i'm not a spammer. Ok, what should i do now to fix my faultness? i will be punished? it's ok, i accepted with a happy heart, trully.

Answer (score 0):

Please include jquery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and It should work

Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/7L7Nd/3/)

Comment: ha yes of course! But the problem is that I've included it in my website and it still does not work. It works in fiddle though, so there must be something wrong elsewhere. I'll try to post all the html.

Comment: @user1098555 you didnt included the jquery in the jsfiddle so How was I supposed to know . Can you show your test page , Please??

Comment: you could not know, and I had not noticed it either. What I'm saying is that I realize that it was missing in the jsfiddle but in my website I've included it, so the problem must be elsewhere. However I've noticed now that the reason it's not closing is because it seems that clicking on the closing button triggers a form validation instead. I'll have to figure it out. I've updated my original post with all the html (it's asp.net mvc)

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to reference this:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I had same problem. I added it, and it worked.