# Why is Bootstrap alert invisible?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an alert in my Asp.Net Mvc application. I am using this html, basically taken straight from the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing) website:

```
<div id="notifications" style="z-index: 1" padding="10">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert1" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    This is an Alert.
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I load the page, the alert takes up the proper space on the page, but is invisible. I can find the close button by slowly strafing my mouse over the region, and clicking on it does dismiss the alert, but at no point is anything visible. I thought that `z-index: 1` might have fixed it, but no such luck.

I have also tested this on a new Asp.Net project with the same problem. How do I get the alert to display properly?

Comment: Works fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/61jx3dn1/  There must be something else interfering on your page.  You'll need to edit your question and provide a working example of the problem.  Otherwise, there's no way for us to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide a sample where we have your html, css and js so that the error can be reproduced

Comment: The HTML you've provided functions as expected when you include Bootstrap's CSS. What other CSS are you including in your project? Do you have any JavaScript that targets `.alert`?

Comment: Did you include proper CDN for bootstrap?

Comment: It is literally a new Asp.Net Mvc application (created from VS 2017 template) with the above code added to the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a resource loading order thing (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16035195/244811)).  Try to add the resources in this order:  jQuery then Bootstrap.

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="notifications" style="z-index: 1" padding="10">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert1" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    This is an Alert.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it. I had the resources, but the versions were old.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your html source. Check whether have you referred all the dependancies correctly. In order to add a properly functioning alert you need to have

1. Bootstrap css
2. Jquery
3. Bootstrap js

Remember to use jquery before using bootstrap, otherwise it will give an error. Try out the following snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="notifications" style="z-index: 1" padding="10">
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert1" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button> This is an Alert.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how is this different than my answer?